# Firebase Test Lab result fails radomly

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase-test-lab

I'm currently working on a Unity application, where the app started to crash randomly in the firebase test lab. Earlier, my SDK version was 29 and every time I make an internal test, it works well with no issues. And recently, Google made it mandatory to keep the SDK version to 30. And from there, I started to face errors and failures in the test lab. I tried many different solutions. So sometimes, the test lab returns success with no issues. And I retest the same build, but the second time, it shows that **A native crash was detected**.

These are the logs

```
       *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'xiaomi/cactus/cactus:8.1.0/O11019/V10.3.8.0.OCBMIXM:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 28308, tid: 29315, name: Loading.Preload  >>> com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic <<<
signal 5 (SIGTRAP), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
r0 00000000  r1 00007283  r2 00000005  r3 92ed17c4
r4 92ed17c4  r5 092514a0  r6 092514a0  r7 0000010c
r8 0937f034  r9 b2d281b8  sl 0937f088  fp 9274473b
ip 000005ae  sp 0937f028  lr 9274460b  pc b2cdb134  cpsr 000b0010
backtrace:
#00 pc 0004a134  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 005ff607  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#02 pc 005ff8df  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#03 pc 001374e1  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#04 pc 00135b61  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#05 pc 00135e15  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#06 pc 00135dc1  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#07 pc 001ff37d  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#08 pc 000722a1  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#09 pc 0018486f  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#10 pc 00166895  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#11 pc 00167785  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#12 pc 0026743b  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#13 pc 00260ebb  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#14 pc 002612b5  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#15 pc 001ca08f  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#16 pc 001cb291  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#17 pc 001cb16d  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#18 pc 001cb103  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#19 pc 0020f2d3  /data/app/com.TrilokGames.DownHillRepublic-xgGjUWrtsFtpacSFL7xYQw==/lib/arm/libunity.so
#20 pc 00047507  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
#21 pc 0001af75  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Unity Editor to something above 2020.